# How to refactor w/o localStorage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I wrote a script to show a visitor to a website a different random image per day. I'm a Javascript noob so I was pretty proud when I got this to work. However, I used localStorage save the random variable so if you visit the page on the same day you'll see the same image. Now I realize that because of this if you open a different browser (or different computer) you can get a different image on the same day. I would like for all users to see the same image in a day.

However, every time I rewrite the script to get rid of the localStorage random, my code breaks and I can't figure out why. Like I said, I'm learning Javascript so I think I am just missing something fundamental that might be obvious to someone more advanced. Can anyone help me out?

Here is the code that works but depends on localStorage:

```
var now = new Date();
var day = now.getDay();
var checkDay = localStorage.getItem('day');
var checkRandom = localStorage.getItem('random');

function Random(){
    var random = [Math.floor(Math.random()*846+1)];
    localStorage.setItem('random', JSON.stringify(random));
}

//If user has never visited before, define random.

if (checkRandom === null) {
    Random();
}

(function() {

//If user has never visited before or if it's a different day,
//remove old random, reroll, append to div, set localStorage day.

if ( checkDay === null || checkDay != day) {
 (function() {
    localStorage.removeItem('random');
    Random();
    var today = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('random'));
    image = '<img src=\"' + today + '.png\">';
    $(image).appendTo($('#result'));
    localStorage.removeItem('day');
    localStorage.setItem('day', JSON.stringify(day));

})();
} else {
    //Else will fire if user visits on the same day.
    //Retrieve previous random and append to div.

    var today = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('random'));
    image = '<img src=\"' + today + '.png\">';
    $(image).appendTo($('#result'));

}
})();
```

Here's my attempt to refactor the code to do everything the same but avoid localStorage for random. However, this keeps telling my var random is undefined in the else statement. I can't figure out why as it seems essentially the same as the original.

```
var now = new Date();
var day = now.getDay();
var checkDay = localStorage.getItem('day');
var setDay = localStorage.setItem('day', JSON.stringify(day));

function Random(){
    var random = [Math.floor(Math.random()*846+1)];
}

if (checkDay === null) {
    Random();
}

(function() {


if ( checkDay != day) {
 (function() {
    Random();
    image = '<img src=\"' + random + '.png\">';
    $(image).appendTo($('#result'));
    localStorage.removeItem('day');
    setDay;

})();
} else {
    image = '<img src=\"' + random + '.png\">';
    $(image).appendTo($('#result'));
}
})();
```

What am I doing wrong and how would you refactor this without localStorage for random?

Comment: How many total random images are available ?

Comment: You should look into generating a repeatable random number that is based on the current day. That way the displayed random image will be the same for all users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript here is being used as a client side scripting language. So, whatever client(browser) you are using, your code will be dependent on that. You can try cookies, localStorage, etc but all of them will be dependent on the browser that opens your JS code. Any other browsers, or the same one in private browsing (incognito) mode, will not be able to maintain state.

If showing same image for one day across all browsers is important to you, you should use some server side language and maintain state on the server. (PHP or even node.js)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there's another issue in your re-factored code on the line

```
var setDay = localStorage.setItem('day', JSON.stringify(day));
```

This will not magically create a reference to that code so you can run it later (as you actually try to) in the if statement by calling it by its name, but instead it stores the returned value of that function call. You also don't need to stringify it, since `Date().getDay()` will return a number, and it will be converted to a string by default when added to the `localStorage`. Just wrap the line in a function and call it like so:

```
var setDay = function(){ localStorage.setItem('day', day) };
```

```
setDay();
```

As for the second part of the problem (`random` being `undefined`), the issues is related to the way scoping works in JS. By defining `random` inside that function, you only allow stuff inside the function to use it. If you want it to be accessible outside the function, define it outside of it. Oh, and by the way, you can put commas after multiple assignments with `var`:

```
var now = new Date(),
    day = now.getDay(),
    checkDay = localStorage.getItem('day'),
    setDay = function(){ localStorage.setItem('day', day) },
    random;
```

This will define the `random` variable in the code's main scope, allowing you to use it in your entire script. Just remove the `var` from inside the function that assigns the random number to a variable. Finally, don't use the `[]` (square brackets) around the number because that creates an array. The only reason why it worked before is that arrays, when stringified, become `"a,b,c,d"`, if it looks like `["a","b","c","d"]`. Arrays with a single element will not have a comma inside them, and this allowed your previous code to work, despite it being incorrect.

```
function Random(){
    random = Math.floor(Math.random()*846+1);
}
```

---

Something else to note is that you won't necessarily be able to identify a user on all browsers the have installed automatically. There are attempts at doing this, like [evercookie](http://samy.pl/evercookie/), but if you want to store information related to a specific person rather than to a specific browser, you'll need some sort of server-side solution to store the user's data and load it if needed (after, for example, requesting a login).

Answer (score 0):

To get a randomized image per day - the same for all visitors - why not forget local storage/cookies and just use an array of image names?
You simply randomize once when you write the array in javascript.
To get the image of the day you increment the array index using the current date.
Make the array long enough and your visitors won't notice if you run through it again
when the index hits the max for your array - e.g. using modulo

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var images = [{
    "01": "image1.png"
}, {
    "02": "image2.png"
}, {
    "03": "image3.png"
}, {
    "04": "image4.png"
}, {
    "05": "image5.png"
}, {
    "06": "image6.png"
}, {
    "07": "image7.png"
}, {
    "08": "image8.png"
}, {
    "09": "image9.png"
}, {
    "10": "image10.png"
}, {
    "11": "image11.png"
}, {
    "12": "image12.png"
}, {
    "13": "image13.png"
}, {
    "14": "image14.png"
}, {
    "15": "image15.png"
}, {
    "16": "image16.png"
}, {
    "17": "image17.png"
}, {
    "18": "image18.png"
}, {
    "19": "image19.png"
}, {
    "20": "image20.png"
}, {
    "21": "image21.png"
}, {
    "22": "image22.png"
}, {
    "23": "image23.png"
}, {
    "24": "image24.png"
}, {
    "25": "image25.png"
}, {
    "26": "image26.png"
}, {
    "27": "image27.png"
}, {
    "28": "image27.png"
}, {
    "29": "image29.png"
}, {
    "30": "image30.png"
}, {
    "31": "image31.png"
}];
// day of month / today
var now = new Date().toJSON().split("-").slice(-1)[0].slice(0, 2); 
$.each(images, function (k, v) {
    if (now in v) {
        $("<img>", {
            "src": v[now]
        })
        .appendTo($("#result"))
    }
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/zv9sh7kq/